How to handle many entities in managed object context and save them to disk only when necessary?
The user in my app can create multiple "Song" entities and add to a playlist in the range of 10k to 100k.
I don't think I can use NSBatchInsertRequest to save them until they press "Done" since that will save them permanently to disk straight away.
I want the user to have the option to rollback to their previous state of their playlist by pressing on "Cancel" button.
For example, their playlist originally has only 1 song and they added 10k more songs to that playlist and they pressed cancel instead thus reverting back to the 1 song state.
How do I handle this situation? Right now, my app freezes for 5 to 10 seconds with over gigabytes of memory usage.
My data model:
extension Playlist {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Playlist> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?

    var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? "Unknown Playlist"
    }
    
    var wrappedId: UUID {
        id ?? UUID()
    }
}

extension Song {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Song> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Song>(entityName: "Song")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var fileExtension: String?
    @NSManaged public var artist: String?
    @NSManaged public var playlistId: UUID? //The playlist the song belongs to
    @NSManaged public var playlistIndex: Int64 //The index in which the song is at in a playlist

    var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? "Unknown Song"
    }
    
    var wrappedFileExtension: String {
        fileExtension ?? "Unknown File Extension"
    }
    
    var wrappedArtist: String {
        artist ?? "Unknown Artist"
    }
    
    var wrappedPlaylistId: UUID {
        playlistId ?? UUID()
    }
}

func savePlaylist(for playlistId: UUID) {
//moc is the main queue's managed object context

                        for i in 0...100000 {
                            let song = Song(context: moc)
                            song.name = "Song" + " \(i)"
                            song.fileExtension = "mp3"
                            song.artist = "Some artist"
                            song.playlistId = playlistId
                        }
                        
                        try? moc.save()
}


Once it's saved, it's saved. You need to keep the entities in a background context, and reset() on "Cancel", or save() on "Done".

But won’t having 100k items on a background context cause high memory usage?

As a user add 100k items, it wouldn't surprise me to take some time. A freeze is an issue, add a HUD/spinner... But you say with 1 or 5 items, and at the same time 100k items... It's unclear...

It can be in the range from 1 to 100k items. Will the system force kill the app when adding this many objects in a background managed object context?

It will if you use too much RAM, but app are allowed to do heavy stuff... Also, if you have 100k, you can do 10 times 10k, doing batches if needed... But here, a BatchInsertRequest seems better...

If I were to use a batch insert, how do I rollback the changes then since it is saved permanently?

Please edit your question and show us the data model.

I have edited the question and have posted the core data model code. I currently do not have a relationship between Song and Playlist since I wanted to use NSBatchInsertRequest expecting a large number of songs in a playlist which does not support relationships thus chose to have an attribute called "playlistId" instead.

You're fighting the framework. If you want to do it this way, you'll be better off managing the objects directly, or using a database like SQLite. Also: what does the UX look like if I'm going to insert 100k songs?? At 3 minutes per song, that's about 7 months of music, non-stop.

Your data model doesn't reflect the problem you're trying to solve.
Add a second Entity, a Playlist, with an ordered many-to-many relationship to Song. Add songs to the playlists as needed. There's no reason for you to instantiate and fault in all 100k Songs. As long as they're only saved to external storage, your memory usage will be low. But the code you've posted will instantiate all of them, in memory, simultaneously, and that's going to hurt you a lot.

No. If you're inserting 7 months of songs into a persistent store in one shot, you will be requiring a lot of memory. If they're all instantiated at once, you need memory to hold them all at once. The point of Core Data is that you shouldn't have to instantiate them at once. I think you have chosen the wrong tool for what you're asking to achieve.
